# Python - identify items from list where sublist items are duplicated

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Awful title, please rename or generalise as appropriate.

Scenario:

```
inputList = [[1, "Data x"], [2, "Data z"], [3, "Data x"]]
```

I want to find where there are duplicates of index[1].

```
DesiredOutput = [[1, "Data x"], [3, "Data x"]]
```

Ideally, the [1] would be another list, instead of a string:

```
[[1, ["Data x1", "Data x2"], [2,  ["Data x1", "Data x2"]]
```

Comment: Tuple are acceptable instead of lists?

Comment: `[[1, ["Data x1", "Data x2"], [2,  ["Data x1", "Data x2"]]` is not a proper list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about (just an alternative)

```
inputList = [[1, "Data x"], [2, "Data z"], [3, "Data x"]]

from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for i, v in enumerate(inputList):
    dd[v[1]].append(i)

dupes = [itemgetter(*v)(inputList) for v in dd.itervalues() if len(v) > 1]
# [([1, 'Data x'], [3, 'Data x'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict here:

```
>>> inputList = [[1, "Data x"], [2, "Data z"], [3, "Data x"]]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> for v, k in inputList:
...     dic[k].append(v)
...     
>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Data z': [2], 'Data x': [1, 3]})
```

As the item in your second example are lists, so you need to convert them to tuples first:

```
for v, k in inputList:
   dic[tuple(k)].append(v)
```

Comment: This works, as long as the values of interest are hashable. In OPs seconds example, the values (lists) are not hashable, although that might be quickly fixed with a `tuple`.

Comment: Adding to my own comment here. There has been some discussion about a `freeze` protocol for python. Even a rejected [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0351/) back in 2005. More discussion here: http://www.animats.com/papers/languages/pythonconcurrency.html. - Seems like OPs problem would be a *use-case*.

Comment: @miku `frozensets` could be used here.

Answer (score 1):

```
inputList = [[1, "Data x"], [2, "Data z"], [3, "Data x"]]

DesiredOutput = [] # Create empty list

for x in inputList:  
    if x[1] == inputList[0][1]: #compare reference value with each item in inputList 
        DesiredOutput.append(x)  
print(DesiredOutput)

#[[1, "Data x"], [3, "Data x"]]
```

Comment: For me, this wins for simplicity. I remain open to persuation if this isn't performant though (I forgot to mention that inputList has perhaps around 20000 items).

Comment: This is not a generic solution. @Jon Clements's solution would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = [[1, "Data x"], [2, "Data z"], [3, "Data x"]]
desired_output = [x for x in input_list if x[1] == input_list[0][1]]
print(desired_output)
```